# Microsoft Azure - how to locate ML models

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-sdk-python

I have been writing Python for a number of years and I'm at a fairly decent level. I have never formally studied Computer Science.

I have been reading about and using Azure Cognitive Services for one of my applications which uses the Microsoft Azure Cognitive Service' **textanalytics** service for Language Detection based on text input. As per my understanding Microsoft (MS) has trained some powerful ML models that are used for their cognitive services package.

I understand that all the code is open source:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/textanalytics/azure-ai-textanalytics/azure/ai/textanalytics

And I am able to do some basic navigation through the SDK documentation and repo to solve my purpose. However, I want to understand that if Microsoft does use a ML model for the text analytics service or any other cognitive service where is the actual model saved in the repository.

While navigating the repository I was expecting to find a call to some sort of serialized file (eg .pkl, .yaml) which loads the model and makes a prediction / returns an output. However, for the life of me, after spending a couple of hours I am lost in this massive repo with no results.

To make it easier, I'd be interested to know **where Microsoft saves the actual ML models** in the repo with an example reference to any of the cognitive services. If that is not the case, how are these models used within the code to return predictions / responses?

Answer (score 0):

If i can answer more precisely to your ask ,  Azure Cognitive Service for Language is a cloud-based service which  provides Natural Language Processing features for understanding and analyzing text and gives us output.

From this Microsoft Documentation you can find [***`the sample code to create TEXT ANALYTICS client library using Python`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-python/textanalytics-samples/).

For more information please refer this BLOG [***Azure lesson to create text analytics using Azure Portal***](https://azurelessons.com/language-detection-azure-cognitive-service/) & MS DOC: [***Deploy a model for use with Cognitive Search***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-model-cognitive-search)